# How to convert json object containing object arrays into url encoded format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typescript, urlencode

I am trying to convert json object to url encoded format but my json contains array objects so jQuery.param() function is not working. please tell me how to achieve this.
This is the json:

```
{"details":
 [
   {"product_name":"knee 
   cap","price":"123","quantity":"2","size":"small","color":"blue"}, 
   {"product_id":2,"product_name":"soft 
   pillow","price":"123","quantity":"2","size":"small","color":"blue"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I would suggest to pass the JSON data in the body as a POST

Comment: Server not accepting json format. That's why I am trying to convert to url encoded string

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to pass the JSON data as a POST request but if you want to pass in URL use this :

```
 var result = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object_to_be_serialised))
```

```js
const params = {
  "details": [{
    "product_name": "knee cap",
    "price": "123",
    "quantity": "2",
    "size": "small",
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_name": "soft pillow",
    "price": "123",
    "quantity": "2",
    "size": "small",
    "color": "blue"
  }]
}

document.write(
  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params))
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a JavaScript solution, which runs in the browser ...

1. You can convert any JavaScript object into a string via `JSON.stringify`
2. You can url encode any string with the `encodeURIComponent` function

Example:

```
const json = {details: [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}]};
const s = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json));
console.log(s);
```

This will give you:

```
%7B%22details%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22foo%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22bar%22%7D%5D%7D
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var l = {
  details: [
    {
      product_name: "kneecap",
      price: "123",
      quantity: "2",
      size: "small",
      color: "blue"
    },
    {
      product_id: 2,
      product_name: "soft pillow",
      price: "123",
      quantity: "2",
      size: "small",
      color: "blue"
    }
  ]
};

function encode(obj, prefix) {
  var str = [],
    p;
  for (p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p,
        v = obj[p];
      str.push(
        v !== null && typeof v === "object"
          ? encode(v, k)
          : encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v)
      );
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
}

console.log(encode(l));
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/wXyQNv)

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.

Comment: What does that prefix attribute mean?

Comment: @nff well prefix mean when need to add parent to your object.for ex: of you put 'test' as prefix to your object, in your backend you can access it something like this:  test[details][0]['product_name'] otherwise:  details[0]['product_name']